# How should UTM parameters be configured in Google Search Console URL parameters tool?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, url-parameters

One of my client has URL parameters on the main category pages on the website (e.g. `www.example.com/category?utm_parameter`)for some tracking.

Will adding these parameters to GWT as ‘Let Googlebot decide’ impact the performance organically for the main URLs? as there are no duplicate pages. Should these be blocked?

Comment: Are these the standard UTM parameters used by Google Analytics?   If so, there usually isn't any need to configure them.   Googlebot knows to ignore them be default.

Answer (score 1):

To be extra cautious and prevent unwanted duplicate content issue, there are 2 basic things you can do.

**First on Google Search Console :**

1. Declare UTM parameters in URL parameters tool.
2. For select box "Does this parameters change page content seen by the user?", pick No. UTM are passive parameters, they have no impact on user experience.

You can find official info [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6080550?hl=en&ref_topic=6080547).

**Second, be sure to use rel="canonical"** on your target pages - and more broadly to your entire site.